# Programmatically edit iOS project to be universal

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to alter the setting that defines whether the XCode project is iPhone, iPad or Universal.

I can alter most of the other settings programmatically with the Info.plist file.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you continue with your effort to programmatically edit a project?  The solution is in the project file, not in the info.plist file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting for device deployment, Universal or iPhone-only or iPad-only, is not in Info.plist. It's in project.pbxproj.

Check all `XCBuildConfiguration` objects for a key called `buildSettings`.

Within buildSettings, set the TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY key accordingly:

- iPhone = 1
- iPad = 2
- Universal = 1,2

I haven't done this myself, so I don't know if there are any specific project keys that are **required** by either device family, and *exclusive* to that family.

Comment: This might come in handy if you want to have different settings for the device family for Debug and Release, which Xcode doesn't support out of the box.